# Is the untested/empty statement true?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I stumbled upon this logic question in a math class recently.

My teacher told us that a statement that is not tested/is empty is true. For example, that if I stated that: "if the team A wins the game, I am gonna buy you a coke", and then team B goes on and wins the game, the statement would be true, independent of me buying a coke. Could anybody elaborate how this can be the case, and why?

It came up as an explanation to why the the empty-set is both an open and a closed set.

Comment: See [Vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Comment: An see [Clopen set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clopen_set).

Comment: Yes, every flying dragon is a millionaire.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is, this is true because we have adopted that resolution by convention, because, for all its faults, doing so comes closest to resembling the intuitive notion of 'if-then' while having a definite logical value in all mathematical situations.  To see what I am getting at, consider the following 'truth table':

```
A | B | A-->B

T | T | T

T | F | F

F | T | *

F | F | *
```

This illustrates the truth about our intuitive notion of 'if-then' - When A is true, B has to be true, *and when A is false we don't care*.  But mathematical logic doesn't allow 'we don't care', so we have to replace the '*'-s with definite truth-values.  Then the question becomes: how do we do so and still match our intuition?  There are clearly four possible resolutions:

```
A | B | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4

T | T | T | T | T | T

T | F | F | F | F | F

F | T | F | F | T | T

F | F | F | T | F | T
```

If we choose (1) to mean 'if-then', we are saying 'if A is true then B is true' means 'A and B are both true', and we are also implying 'if B is true then A is true'.  But this is clearly not what we want: When we have both 'A-->B' and 'C-->B', this would be saying 'A, B, and C' are all true together'; this doesn't work because sometimes we need A and C to be mutually-exclusive *(typical example: a number-theory proof-by-cases, where A means 'n is even' and C means 'n is odd')*.  A similar problem occurs if we choose (2), which says 'A and B are both true -or- both false'.  If we choose (3) to mean 'if-then' we are saying 'if A is true then B is true' means merely 'B is true' - REGARDLESS of A.  Clearly that also doesn't work - generally we want B to depend on A *somehow*.  So all that is left is (4).

Comment: "we have adopted that resolution by convention" - no.

Comment: @PMar : Are you the same user as the following other PMar:  http://math.stackexchange.com/users/347147, http://math.stackexchange.com/users/325605, http://math.stackexchange.com/users/344183, http://math.stackexchange.com/users/357091, http://math.stackexchange.com/users/358074, https://math.stackexchange.com/users/369583, https://math.stackexchange.com/users/370376, http://math.stackexchange.com/users/386375, http://math.stackexchange.com/users/380039. If this is the case, could you please [merge](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your accounts?

Answer (score 4):

Do you understand that the conditional $p\rightarrow q$ is true whenever $p$ is false, or whenever $q$ is true?

I think the best way of representing the truth of a condition $p\rightarrow q$ is knowing that $p\rightarrow q$ IS TRUE, UNLESS both $p$ is true, and $q$ is false.

With two variables, $p, q,$ there are four possible assignments of truth values, each represented below.

[image]

For example, let's say you promise $p$: = Team A wins the game.  Let $q$: = "I'll buy you a Coke."

First of all, you never made any promise about what you'll give me if Team A loses.  So if $\lnot p$, I can't accuse you of making a false statement, whether you give me a Coke or not.  And in the case that team A wins and you buy me a Coke, well, you've made good on your promise.

The **only** way you'd be lying is if team A wins ($p$), and you don't buy me a Coke $(\lnot q).$

---

Another classic example.

The empty set is a subset of every set.

Let's simply look at some arbitrary set $A$:  If any set $B$ is a subset of $A$, then we know by definition that $b\in B \rightarrow b \in A$. Suppose now that $B =\varnothing$.  Well, $\varnothing \subseteq A$ because if $b \in \varnothing,$ then $b\in A$.  Well, there's no $b\in \varnothing$, but the definition still holds because "$b \in \varnothing$ is false, which makes $b \in \varnothing \rightarrow b \in A$ true

Comment: My problem here is, that I don't think that the statement is false either. That is not what i'm proposing. I just think that the statement is neither, since it is not confirmed or denied. It is neither true or false. (Maybe not possible)

Comment: How can you explain the conclusion 3 and 4 in your scheme.

Comment: To me the problem with such explanations is that they leave the impression that the truth table of the right arrow is a theorem rather than a definition. I like to ask people to define it differently and see if they can express any mathematical truth in a succinct and elegant way using this new definition.

Comment: And reading the OPs comments before mine shows that exactly this happened: he is now wondering about philosophy instead of math

Comment: @Bananach, agreed, and hence my two examples. If I promise that $x\rightarrow q,$ What would constitute a lie?  The only way I would be lying (my statement deemed false), is if $x$ is true and $y$ is false.  The definition itself of the material conditions says everything implication is true, provided you don't lie: provided $\lnot(x\land \lnot y)$.

Comment: You seem to say, that if a something is not a lie, then it is true. Maybe one of my problems of intuition is, that converse of lie is a truth. I would seem to think it was "not lie" and you seem to say, it is "truth", am I wrong?.

I highly appreciate the help.

Comment: Viktor:  I understand that the definition of the (material) conditional (when it's true and when it's false) seems counter-intuitive.  Refer to [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).  Also, understand that the material conditional $p\to q$ and it's truth has nothing to do with whether $p$ is relevant to $q$, nor does it require any relevance between $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am not very skilled in logic, but I wasn't aware of the definition beforehand, so I thank you for clarifying . Unfortunately I cannot accept 2 answers, but I would have accepted yours as well. ( A true statement by the way ;) )

Comment: I completely understand the counter-intuition.  The conditional, actually, does, in fact, consider that if "not true", if not  "lying", if not "false", then it's true.  Of course, in other areas like topology, "not open" does not mean "closed"...etc.  Take a look at [paradoxes of material conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradoxes_of_material_implication)

Answer (score 3):

Without going into a formal treatment, what your teacher means is:

The statement $$\forall x\in X: A (x) \Rightarrow B (x) $$    is true if $A (x) $ is false for all $ x\in X$ , no matter what $ B $ is.

That your teacher is right follows from the DEFINITION of the right arrow $\Rightarrow $,  that is, it follows from the fact that the truth table of this symbol always assigns "True" when the first argument is false.

There is no epistemological claims behind what your teacher said.

Comment: You've done nothing other than spitting back the definition of the the conditional only in those circumstances  when the antecedent is false. You provide no justification, or down-to-earth example.  The OP's example is not universally quantified, so all the more abstract and "philosophical" your answer is.

Answer (score 1):

The general idea at which you are hinting is that of conditional probability, which states that for two events, $P$ and $Q$, the statement $P$ *implies* $Q$ is given by

$$(P \implies Q) \iff (Q \lor \lnot P),$$

where "$\implies$" denotes the implication operator.

To better understand this, consider the following timely scenario. A politicians states: $$\textrm{"If } \underbrace{\textrm{I win the elections, }}_{\textrm{Statement } P} \textrm{then } \underbrace{\textrm{taxes will go down"}}_{\textrm{Statement } Q}.$$ This statement would have a truth value of $T$ is he/she does not lie, and a truth value of $F$ if he/she does lie.

- If $P$ is $T$, and $Q$ is $T$, then the politician has not lied; he/she was elected, and taxes went down. Hence $P \implies Q$ is $T$.
- If $P$ is $T$, and $Q$ is $F$, then the politician has lied; he/she was elected, and taxes did not go down. Hence $P \implies Q$ is $F$
- If $P$ is $F$, regardless of what $Q$ is, the politician cannot lie; he/she was never elected, and so never got the opportunity to lie. Hence $P \implies Q$ is $T$.